# XmlNode in a C# portable project

Tags: c#, portability

I'm trying to read and use some XML files in a portable C# project,
but it can't find the `XmlNode` class.

I tried to add the System.Xml assembly but I saw this message in the references window:

> All of the Framework assemblies are already referenced. Please use the Object
>   browser to explore the references in the Framework.

Why can't I use the XML assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties and ensure you're targeting at least Framework 3.0

Comment: If you right-click the project and "Add References" can you add the latest version of System.Windows assembly?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, what version?

Comment: If you start a fresh project, are you able to add the assembly then? (sorry, trying to narrow down the issue)